# how do i make a set from a map keys

Tags: java, set, treemap

I'm trying to extract keys from a map to a set.
The keys are objects with 2 primitive param,
how do i make it non duplicate set by the param i want?
The code below is the method and the param is the account.
I want to make the set non duplicate by the balance of the acc.

```
public static Map<Account, MyLinkedList<Customer>> getAccounts() {
    Map<Account, MyLinkedList<Customer>> AccMap = new TreeMap<>(new AccountComparator());

    System.out.print("Please enter how many accounts: ");
    int accNumber = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println();
    for(int i = 1; i <= accNumber; i++){
        System.out.print("Account # " + i +". Number of customers: ");
        int cusNumber = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
        //Account acc = new Account(accountID++, (int)(Math.random()*200-100));

        MyList<Customer> cusList = new MyLinkedList<>();
        cusList = getCustomers(cusNumber);
        AccMap.put(new Account(accountID++, (int)(Math.random()*200-100)), (MyLinkedList<Customer>) cusList);       
    }

    System.out.println(AccMap.toString());
    return AccMap;
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about turning `Map<Account, MyLinkedList<Customer>> ` into a `Set<Account>`? Or something different? Maps already have a `keySet()` method which returns all the keys in a Set, and Sets are already non-duplicated (as are the keys in a Map) so it's a bit confusing that you're concerned about duplicates.

Comment: no, the keys in the map are objects (Account),
the Account object has 2 pramas .
i want to to use the balance as the unique value

Comment: Then what you want is a map of account balance to account, not a set (and how are you going to ensure that balances are unique? What if two accounts have the same balance?)

Comment: can you please show me what you mean?
because i still think that a set is the solution, it's just that i'm missing something, just don't know what :).
btw , if 2 acc has the same balance i wont count 1 of them.
lets say i have 2 acc in my bank the first and second have 20 USD the function will count only 1 because they have the same balance.

Comment: This must be a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Maps have a method called [keyset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) which returns all the keys to the map as a set.   Because of the way that maps work, it is already unique on the keys (in your case the `Account` object).  However, it checks for uniqueness using the account comparator and equals methods.

If your `AccountComparator` class only compares `accountID` then that should give what you want.

If your comparator includes both parameters then you could potentially have problems.

Comment: the accountComparator class is using the account balance to compare between accounts. not the accountID. im using a treemap to keep it sorted by the account balance.

Comment: if i understand you ,
this line should work :
accMap.keySet().size()?
the target is to tell how many accounts has different balance.

Comment: What's the rationale behind the use of a Map then? Couldn't you just override the `hashCode()` method and put the objects in a `HashSet` and get the size of the hash set?

Comment: no, because the map holds the Account as a key and a linked list of customers as entry.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just iterate the set obtained from keySet method invoked on the map, and then remove the duplicates while iteration? Or you can even iterate the set obtained from entrySet method and filter out the duplicates while iterating, and save the remains in another set. I don't think there could be any simpler way :/

Comment: i need to do it in 1 line :/ that's the requirements.